# I can't install Joomla because Zlib Compression Support no

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I'm trying to install Joomla 3 on docker server using php 5.3.29 but I can't because :

```
Zlib Compression Support  no
```

In Pre-Installation Check

I tried every thing found on internet but still having that stack; my php.ini file is configured to support zlib
my php.ini file is set to :

```
; http://php.net/zlib.output-compression
zlib.output_compression = On

; http://php.net/zlib.output-compression-level
zlib.output_compression_level = -1

; You cannot specify additional output handlers if zlib.output_compression
; is activated here. This setting does the same as output_handler but in
; a different order.
; http://php.net/zlib.output-handler
zlib.output_handler = ""

; zlib so
extension=zlib.so
```

but still can't install joomla.

Comment: Have you run phpinfo.php under your environment to see if the Zlib has been been installed with your php environment?

Comment: in phpinfo zlib is disable I tryied everything but still disable

Answer (score 1):

As your problem is not really with Joomla but with Docker and PHP this is probably not the best area to be asking about this issue.

A quick google search with 'stackexchange docker php' came up a few potential causes for your issue from some compression libraries not install by default to instruction for how you need to set up your Docker environment.

Comment: I did evry solution found on google but no luck